# Removing a character (^) from each row of panda Dataframe and get unique words in each row

Tags: python

I want to replace '^' by ' ' (space) in each row of dataframe [df] and then find unique words in each row .

Thanks

```
        ID              Text
0   B07HFHF2ZM  NaN
1   B07HFK5V4K  handloom saree^handloom cotton sarees^bengal h...
2   B07HFKHRTL  tantuja bengal handloom sarees^handloom saree^...
3   B07HFKLPL5  handloom sarees cotton bengal^bengal cotton sa...
4   B07HFKXWW3  cotton saree^bengal cotton sarees for women^ta...
5   B07HFL8J2D  tantuja bengal handloom sarees^handloom saree^...
6   B07HZY27MF  cotton saree^tantuja bengal handloom sarees^co...
7   B07HZZCH28  tantuja^tantuja bengal handloom sarees^cotton ...
8   B07J163MGJ  tangail saree handloom cotton^black cotton sar...
9   B07J191MR4  tantuja saree^bengal cotton sarees for women^b...
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to replacement, You were close.
This should work:

```
df['Text 2'] = pd.Series(map(lambda x: str(x).replace("^"," "), df['Text']))
```

In python3 `map` creates a generator, you have to run the generator in order to get the result. Usually you can do `list(map(...))` but in this case a `pandas.Series` is preferable as you want to create a dataframe column.

I also needed to change `x.str.replace` into `str(x).replace` to make it work and the `"c"` with `" "`. If you want spaces, use a space, not the 'c' character.

To look for unique words you can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
for row in df['Text2']:
    wordcounter = Counter(row.split())
    for w, i in wordcounter.items():
        if i == 1:
            print(w, end=' ')
    print('')
```

This will print for each line with all the unique words (words that appear once).
If you need all the words (just skipping the repetiton) you can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead.

```
for row in df['Text2']:
    wordcounter = set(row.split())
    print(wordcounter)
```

Of course instead of printing you can add them to a list, depending on what you want to do with these unique words.

Comment: added a solution for both cases

Comment: That would be indeed faster

Comment: @Ishan If this answer was helpful, please consider to accept / upvote it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @valentiono - i have upvoted it , my reputation is less than 15 so it won't show  it now , but it will when my reputation > 15